# How to Implement DockPanel or Image click using ICommand?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, image, mvvm, dockpanel

Here's a little background before I start. I started creating my application in WPF the same way I used to program in WinForms. Obviously, this is completely bypassing the strength of WPF. So now that I've read more on WPF and the MVVM framework, I'm starting to adapt my application to work in the Model - View - ViewModel way.

Beforehand, I used to have code-behind of my Window and just handled the MouseDown RoutedEvents to then proceed and prompt a window for a signature. My DockPanel and Image don't seem to have a `Command`.

How can I do this the MVVM way? Are RoutedEvents the way to go for this situation?

Comment: you can use behaviors or attached properties , there you can register to events and invoke commands

Comment: Instead of complicating the whole thing with Behaviors and stuff, put all your UI elements inside the `ControlTemplate` of a `Button` and use it's `Command`.

Comment: @HighCore Ahh ... So I'd be basically keeping the look of my dock panel but using the button's command property? I think this is the way I'd go... Feel free to post it as an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of complicating the whole thing with Behaviors and stuff, put all your UI elements inside the ControlTemplate of a Button and use it's Command:

```
<Button Command="{Binding YourCommand}">
   <Button.Template>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
          <DockPanel>
             <Image/>
             <!-- Whatever -->
          </DockPanel>
      </ControlTemplate>
   </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use interactivity triggers which comes with [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801).

**Steps** -

- Add a reference to assembly `System.Windows.Interactivity`.
- Add a corresponding namespace in XAML file

  `xmlns:interactivity="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"`

You can use it like for an example -

```
<StackPanel>
   <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
      <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
        <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"/>
      </interactivity:EventTrigger>
   </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>            
</StackPanel>
```

Here CloseCommand is in your ViewModel class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll do a little more research on that.

Answer (score 1):

For implement Image click:

1. Write a class that extends **System.Windows.Control.Image**.
2. Create a **RoutedEvent** and **RoutedEventHandler** to facilitate the mouse
   click event.
3. Override **OnMouseLeftButtonDown**

In my example, I evaluate the click count, because have not idea how do this better

```
public class ImageHelper : Image
    {
        public static readonly RoutedEvent MouseLeftButtonClick =
            EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
                "MouseLeftButtonClick",
                RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
                typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
                typeof(ImageHelper));

        public event RoutedEventHandler MouseLeftButtonClickEvent
        {
            add
            {
                AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonClick, value);
            }
            remove
            {
                RemoveHandler(MouseLeftButtonClick, value);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ClickCount == 1)
            {
                RaiseEvent(new MouseLeftButtonClickEventArgs(
                    MouseLeftButtonClick, this));
            }
            base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        }

        public class MouseLeftButtonClickEventArgs : RoutedEventArgs
        {
            public MouseLeftButtonClickEventArgs(RoutedEvent routedEvent, object source)
                : base(routedEvent, source)
            {
               // some code.....
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<local:ImageHelper>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonClickEvent">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </local:ImageHelper>
```

Comment: I see... Thanks for the answer, seems a little much though. I'll give it a try